# conditional formula which returns a comment in another table in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Having an excel sheet with a table as below:

[image]

same page with a different table. How can I return the comment to another table.

[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you specifically ask for a formula with `IF` this should work:

```
=IF(A2<60,"Fail",IF(A2<70,"Average",IF(A2<80,"Good",IF(A2<90,"Very good",IF(A2<101,"Excelent")))))
```

Drop it in `B2` and drag it down.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend rearranging your score data like this:

| Score <= | Return value |
| --- | --- |
| 59 | Fail |
| 69 | Average |
| 79 | Good |
| 89 | Very good |
| 100 | Excellent |

Then you can use XLOOKUP:

`=XLOOKUP(A13:A22,A2:A6,B2:B6,"Out of score range",1)`

[image]

If you have older Excel use:

`=INDEX($B$2:$B$6,MATCH(TRUE,$A$2:$A$6>=A13,0))`

This requires being entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`.

This indexes the range `B$2:B$6` (use `$` to lock the row references when dragging the formula) and shows the first row where the `MATCH` condition is met:
Range `A$2:A$6` (note the `$` again) being greater than or equal to the value in `A13` (do not use `$` here, so the row value will change if we drag the formula up/down)

Comment: Is it possible using normal if condition?

Comment: What is *not working as expected*? Don't you have access to XLOOKUP (Office 365)?

Comment: See edit using a somewhat similar solution as how the XLOOKUP works.

Comment: using `XLOOKUP()` is much better and faster than nested `IFs()`